# long delay in MathJax rendering on a certain page

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I edit [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2827102), it takes ages to render the MathJax, quite unlike on other pages, where it's a matter of a second or two. When it does render, the big eqnarray* equation is on a single line extending beyond the right margin, ignoring the explicit line breaks.

This happens in both Firefox 60.0.2 and Safara 11.1.1 under Mac OS 10.13.5. It doesn't happen when I copy the answer to the edit window of another page, so it might be that it's caused not by something in the answer but by something else on the page. It also doesn't happen when the page is simply displayed, only when I edit the answer.

*P.S.*: I just encountered this problem again when editing my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836730). As in the previous case, there's a very long delay in rendering (initially upon opening the edit view it doesn't render at all for up a minute before I make a change), this happens only when editing, and when it does render, the table is messed up and all in two lines with the second one extending way beyond the margin.

*P.P.S.*: Now, after I made and saved an edit, it's working normally again.

Comment: On Arch Linux with Chromium it works fine. Even editing (without saving, of course).

Comment: It works for me now, too.

Comment: Maybe it's a temporal bug, that only manifests itself on certain points in the spacetime continuum. Maybe it's a discontinuity point. Maybe spacetime isn't a continuum after all.

Comment: using google chrome - works fine!

Comment: Please nominate on the election! The community strongly needs someone like you. It is about that they will close & delete all the homework questions and anything.

Comment: @peterh: Thanks for the encouragement. But I already have too many responsibilities and don't want to take on another one that would be very time-intensive when taken seriously. Also, I strongly disagree with the Code of Conduct that's about to be adopted (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/312688#312688) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/313161#313161)), and it would make little sense to enforce a code I disagree with.